# Why does my puppy eat so many things besides his dog food?

Tags: behavior

Why does my dog eat rocks, dirt, sticks, leaves or anything else he finds laying around? I don't know what to do. Thank you.

Comment: He's a puppy. Chewing on things is fun, and chewing on things helps him teethe. You can give him other toys to chew on, but ... He's a puppy. Human infants also explore the world by tasting it. And he's a dog. His mouth is the only "hand" he has. Mouthing things, or chewing on them, is not necessarily eating them.

Answer (score 1):

Normal puppy behavior though I would redirect this to his toys. Sticks and rocks are dangerous, rocks damage teeth and sticks can become lodged it their esophagus and damage their gums. If he's prone to eating things I highly recommend getting pet insurance, it will save your butt in case he gets a foreign body (object lodged in their Gastro intestinal system). It is a very expensive surgery.

If you see him eating this stuff distract him with one of his toys and play with him.